# How to delete a word from first line of a file using bash/shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I want to delete a particular word from first line of a file using shell script

My test.txt is

```
# hello helloworld
Goodday
Goodbye
```

In this I want the bash code which edits test.txt to

```
 # helloworld
 Goodday
 Goodbye
```

I want to delete the string "hello" from the first line

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of *your own* attempt and show it to us, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: And if you work with shell scripts, why did you add the C and C++ tags? Please don't spam unrelated tags.

Comment: @Aravind: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Sed with the `-i` option is one way to do this - see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html